# shuffle! an array n times in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shuffle, playing-cards

I am a semi-newbie to Ruby :*(, so thank you in advance. I'm learning as much as I can and I have searched for hours but can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

I have written this method in a Deck class.

```
def shuffle!
  @cards.shuffle!
end
```

I want to know if, using this method, I can modify it to shuffle the cards array **7** times instead of just once, which it currently does now. If not, do I have to write another method that calls .shuffle! and run that seven times once I initialize a new Deck. Thanks again for anyone that can help :)

Comment: Just a question, why would you want to do it 7 times?

Comment: there's a theory that shuffling 7 times creates optimal randomization.  I asked a mathematician friend about this once and he said "The shuffling algorithm I described (cut the pack perfectly, and then mesh perfectly) has the characteristics of what is known as an "iterative" algorithm, in that it takes the output of the last round as the input for this round, and therefore might be chaotic, with periods of stability alternating with periods of chaotic (i.e. highly complex) behaviour. 7 shuffles might be a boundary point. I think it's likely there is nothing special about 7 shuffles though..."

Comment: Ok, but that is a shuffle of a real deck of cards by a human creating "randomness" in a specific way. The it is totally understandable to do more than once. The shuffle!-method in ruby does not work that way, and will not benefit from multiple shuffles.

Comment: i don't disagree - i'm just saying if there's a reason OP wants to do it 7 times it's probably this.

Comment: The 7-times shuffle thing only applies to imperfect human-hand kinds of shuffles. A correct computer shuffle is already perfect, and doing it more than once will do nothing but waste time.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I've been learning C programming, network programming, and a second course in ruby, so I'm learning a lot right now. I never questioned the fact that it won't make a difference, but now that you mention it, it doesn't make sense. I think it is more of just a learning lesson, and without you guys, I wouldn't have learned, so thank you. I do what is asked of me, DO NOT QUESTION THE HUMANSSSSSS, I'm going to give the method a try now. I was really close with the n.times, only I was writing 7.times, **facepalm**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with some tricks as below,as [Array#shuffle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) don't have such functionality,only *n times*. The doc is saying *If rng is given, it will be used as the random number generator.*

```
def shuffle!(n=7)
  n.times { @cards.shuffle! }
end
```

If you call it `a.shuffle` only one time shuffling will be done on the array `a`.If you call as `a.shuffle(random: Random.new(4))`,then the shuffling time is random on array `a`.

Comment: if you change the signature to def shuffle!(n=7), then the function would be fulfil the requirement more closely, and be one can just use the shuffle! method without specifying how many times to shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to do something along these lines.

```
class Deck

  def initialize(cards)
    @cards = cards
  end

  def shuffle!(n = 7)
    n.times { @cards.shuffle! }
    @cards
  end

end

cards = [1, 2, 3, 4]

Deck.new(cards).shuffle! # => [3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Note that the method will return the value of @cards.

Answer (score 0):

If you're always going to shuffle the deck 7 times, I think you don't need to pass an argument - try this:

```
def shuffle
  7.times {self.shuffle!}
end
```

and in `initialize`

```
def initialize
  #your code here
  @cards.shuffle
end
```